# INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Missing index implementation for values

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database

```
Firebase Database (5.0.1) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Missing index implementation for values
at Error (native)
at ab (/<path to project>/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:42:60)
```

Happens when I’m trying to initialize a database reference. I haven’t even made a query yet. Exact line of crash:
`var ref = admin.database();` previously declared `var admin = require("firebase-admin");`

I've seen other SO posts with the same error message but all were fixed with making sure the path of a database reference was not null, where as I haven't event gotten to adding a path yet and when I did try that the path was not null and I still got the error message

Version Info:

- npm version: 4.3.0
- firebase-admin: 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I may have been overriding a function in the firebase library causing it to crash. Here's the code that messed it up:

```
Object.prototype.values = function(callback) {
    var values = Object.keys(this).map(function(key){
        return dictionary[key];
    });

    callback(values)
}
```